# stop redirecting to next page without filling in the info given in html and css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The problem is if I click the "NEXT" button without filling in the form, it redirects me to the next page.

After clicking the "Next" button, the page goes to the next page without filling out the form. So, how can I stop going to the next page without giving input?

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #f1fb40, #f5fba3);
}
.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 400%;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 25px 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.container .title {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: relative;
}
.container .title::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #71b7e6, #9b59b6);
}
.content form .user-details {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 20px 0 12px 0;
}
form .user-details .input-box {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: calc(100% / 2 - 20px);
}
form .input-box span.details {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.user-details .input-box input {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.user-details .input-box input:focus,
.user-details .input-box input:valid {
  border-color: #9b59b6;
}


form .button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 35px 0;
}

form .button input {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #7469da, #c7a9d3);
}

form .button input:hover {
  /* transform: scale(0.99); */
  background: linear-gradient(-135deg, #84b6da, #978b9c);
}
@media (max-width: 584px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  form .user-details .input-box {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  form .category {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .content form .user-details {
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
  .user-details::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 459px) {
  .container .content .category {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleform.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f5ba79b0f3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Kitchen Owner's Package</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title">Fill the Form</div>
    <div class="content">
      <form onsubmit="sendEmail()"; reset(); return false;>
        <div class="user-details">
          <div class="input-box">
            <span class="details">Kitchen Owner's Name</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
          </div>

          <div class="input-box">
            <span class="details">Cloud Kitchen Name</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your kitchen name" required>
          </div>

          <div class="input-box">
            <span class="details">Choose a package</span>
            <select id="package" name="package">
              <option title="select">Please choose a package from the below list:</option>
              <option value="onemonth">Monthly  @5,000/- BDT</option>
              <option value="sixmonths">Half-Yearly  @25,000/- BDT</option>
              <option value="twelvemonths">Yearly  @50,000/- BDT</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <div class="input-box">
            <span class="details">Payment Method</span>
            <select id="package" name="package">
              <option title="select">Pay Through:</option>
              <option value="onemonth">Bkash</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="button">
          <a href="file:///Users/megatron/Documents/Project/The_Isle_of_Kitchens/SignUp/payment.html">
            <input type="button" value="Next">
          </a>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would recommend disabling the "Next" button until the form elements have content.

Comment: Add `required` attribute to the inputs

Comment: @Millhorn can you please kindly suggest me the codes please?? Thanks in advance!